# In Pixate, how do I add new attributes in my styles?

Tags: ios, objective-c, extending, pixate

Basically, I want to add attributes that aren't currently supported by Pixate, how do I do that?

An example could be for a custom control, or for when, say, iOS8 comes out and there's something new (like tintColor being used everywhere in iOS7), and I want to support it right away instead of waiting for Pixate to patch it.

In short, is there a way to extend functionality in Pixate?  Is there a way to create key value pairs for properties that Pixate doesn't yet support?

Answer (score 5):

There currently isn't a way to add arbitrary properties to the CSS in Pixate 2.x. For 3.0, we are adding an API for extending the CSS with arbitrary properties.

Comment: :) and this will be released when?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, Pixate is an abstraction of the `UIAppearance` API. So if you want to support a style before Pixate does, you probably have two options:

1. Use the new `UIAppearance` options in the new iOS SDK until Pixate releases a patch.
2. Write your own CSS parser and convert your styles to UIAppearance code (wheel: reinvented).

That's my 2 cents. Good luck. :)